# Reading dictionary arrays as float and not as string

Tags: python, numpy, csv, dictionary

I need to exchange some parameters between two files, so I created a dictionary that I write as csv file and then I open it from another file to load them. Parameters are float values and array of float.
Python treats them as strings and I am trying to convert them to float again, without success.

My dict is:

```
dict={
'c_x': ch1_x, #ch1_x is an array of float
'c_y': ch1_y, #ch1_y is an array of float
'c_y': ch3_y, #ch3_y is an array of float
'c_y': ch4_y, #ch4_y is an array of float
't':t_fp, #fp is a float number
'dt':dt #dt is a float number
}
```

I write the csv file as:

```
with open("path/dict.csv", 'w') as csv_file:  
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in dict.items():
       writer.writerow([key, value])
```

and I open it with the code:

```
with open("path/dict.csv") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    mydict = dict(reader)
```

and the result is that everything is recognized as string.
How can I convert back them to float arrays and numbers?

I tried different solutions but I always get the error message

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[-2.8000e-07 -2.7950e-07 -2.7900e-07 ...  9.7185e-06  9.7190e-06\n  9.7195e-06]'

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You are writing a string representation of a numpy array to a csv file, this is probably not what you want, to begin with.

Comment: you have to write that logic yourself, csv is a text-based format. Why don't you just choose another serialization format that preserves all this information? e.g. `pickle`

Comment: When using the solution from the linked question, you will also have to handle 't' and 'dt' separately, if they are single values and not arrays. For example, you could repeat the same value in all rows.

Comment: I tried with the linked solution and finally it solved my problem. Unfortunately my arrays are huge so I preferred to create two different dictionaries, one for vectors and the other one for constants, and to adapt the reading cycles (two). it's not compact but it works. Thank you